# AWS Cognito sign in with username not email

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Have a UserPool where the sign-in is defined by email
[image]

and in node.js (backend) I'm calling:

```
const emailData = {
        Name: 'email',
        Value: request.body.email
    };
    const emailAttribute = new amazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(emailData);
    userPool.signUp( request.body.email, request.body.psw, [emailAttribute], null, (error, data) => { ....
```

**everything works perfect**

I've created a new UserPool this time with username as the sign-in and have questions:
[image]

1. Can I have multiple usernames attached to the same email (kids app that the email is of the parent and there is one user for the parent and one for the child with the same email)
2. If the answer to 1 is `Yes` is there any limitations on the number of users per email? (for example a parent with 3 kids in the app = 4 usernames on 1 email)
3. **Couldn't find any example on how to change my code to have cognito use the username as the signin paramter and how to attach the email.**

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can have multiple accounts having the same email address. Email has to be unique only when you want to use it to sign in.
2. There is no limit. If you are not using email as a username then it becomes a regular attribute (just as any other attribute).
3. You need to specify to use `USER_PASSWORD_AUTH` as an authentication flow, and the provide `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`.

```
cognito.initiateAuth({
    ClientId: '...',
    AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: 'my_test_user',
        PASSWORD: '...'
    }
}, function(err, data) {});
```